# Программа зависает после вызова std::thread::join

Tags: c++, многопоточность

Имеется следующий код

```
std::atomic<bool> StopThread=FALSE;//находится внутри класса
void Finder::StartThread(CString path)
{
    if( ThreadFindFile.joinable() )
    {
        StopThread = TRUE;
        ThreadFindFile.join();
        StopThread = FALSE;
    }
    imageIndex = 0;
    Tmp.ListView.DeleteAllItems();
    ThreadFindFile=std::thread(  (&Finder::findFile),this , path, std::ref(imageIndex) );
}
```

Программа зависает каждый раз когда доходит до join(), с detach() все работает хорошо. Но вопрос почему на join такое происходит?
Сначала думал что происходит взаимоблокировка потока, но после изучения оказалось что такой проблемы нет.
`StopThread` является флагом внутри  `Finder::findFile`, если она `==TRUE`, то делаю `return` из функции.

Update
Добавил код функции которая вызывается потоком

```
void Finder::findFile( CString szPath, int& i )
{
    CFindFile FileSearch;
    CString S = szPath + TEXT( "\\*.*" );
    BOOL bFlag = FileSearch.FindFile( S );
    if( !bFlag )
    {
        MessageBox( ListView_hWnd, TEXT( "Error" ), TEXT( "File not found" ), 0 );
    }
    else
    {
        do
        {
            if( FileSearch.IsDots() )
            {
                continue;
            }
            else
            {
                if( StopThread )
                {
                    return;
                }
                if( FileSearch.IsDirectory() )
                {
                    findFile( FileSearch.GetFilePath(), i );
                }
                view_List( FileSearch.GetFileName(), i, FileSearch.GetFilePath() );
                i++;
            }
        } while( FileSearch.FindNextFileW() );
        FileSearch.Close();
    }
    Tmp.ListView.SetImageList( hSmall, 1 );
}


void Finder::view_List( CString name, int i, CString path )
{
    LVITEM lvItem;
    SHFILEINFOW lp{};
    CString nameWithoutEx = std::get<0>( split( name ) );
    CString extention = std::get<1>( split( name ) );
    lvItem.mask = LVIF_IMAGE | LVIF_TEXT;
    lvItem.state = 0;
    lvItem.stateMask = 0;
    lvItem.iItem = i;
    lvItem.iImage = i;
    lvItem.iSubItem = 0;
    lvItem.pszText = const_cast< LPWSTR >( nameWithoutEx.GetString() );
    lvItem.cchTextMax = nameWithoutEx.GetLength();
    Tmp.ListView.InsertItem( &lvItem );
    Tmp.ListView.SetItemText( i, 1, extention.GetString() );
    Tmp.ListView.SetItemText( i, 2, path.GetString() );
    DWORD num = GetFileAttributesW( path.GetString() );
    SHGetFileInfoW( path.GetString(), num, &lp, sizeof( lp ),
                    SHGFI_SYSICONINDEX | SHGFI_ICON | SHGFI_USEFILEATTRIBUTES );
    hSmall.AddIcon( lp.hIcon );
    DestroyIcon( lp.hIcon );
}
```

Comment: Просто ждет, когда поток завершится...

Comment: Может, это условие всегда выполняется `if( FileSearch.IsDots() )`?

Comment: Не вижу код `FileSearch.IsDots()`. А проверяете ли вы там условие остановки или нет?

Comment: FileSearch::IsDots() это функция библиотеки которая убирает такие файлы как ```.``` и ```..```(это системные папки и они мне не нужны. Моя программа обходит нужную директорию, и выводит название файла, расширение и полный путь в CListViewCtrl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

join ждет, пока поток завершится. А если потом чем то занят (например, перекладывает с пустого в порожнее или крутит бесконечный цикл) и не думает завершатся, то ждать join будет долго долго.

Если же потоку сделали detach, то как бы говорите "поток, ты себе там работай, join тебе звать никто не будет". И все. И ничего не "зависает".

Нужен ли join или нет в Вашей конкретной ситуации? а кто его знает, никто же не знает, чем поток занимается и почему Вы решили его подождать. Если результат работы потока Вам очень нужен, то подождать стоит. Но вот ждать в gui потоке точно не стоит. Плюс, Ваша функция называется "запустить поток", а она на самом деле пытается его подождать.

Comment: Ну так прелесть то в том что там стоит булевый флаг, который должен сделать преждевременный выход из функции. Но почему-то поток потом продолжает чего-то ждать. detach() использовать не хочу так как не уверен в том что когда программа завершится поток не будет работать с данными.

Comment: Я просто не понимаю с чем связано это зависание если atomic говорит о том чтобы вернуться... Или как тогда лучше реализовать чтобы моя функция все таки при выставлении флага завершалась?....

Comment: А кто его знает, как устроена функция потока внутри. То, что Вы назвали переменную StopThread и сделали ее atomic, ещё не достаточно.

Comment: Добавил код в вопрос. Самое интересное то что мне консоль пишет что поток завершен, но программа как зависла так и висит.

Comment: пересмотрел код ещё раз. Я правильно понимаю, что вначале в коде идет join, а потом собственно запуск этого потока?

Comment: Не совсем. Если поток запущен, то для него вызывается join() и потом уже идет создание потока. В противном случае поток заново создается.

Логика была такова что, если поток работает, дожидаться его завершения и запускать новый.

Comment: даже если это так, не стоит делать это в главном потоке.